# Issue with pagination in PagedList MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am using MVC **PagedList** to handle **pagination** in my project. Everything works fine except that in my **controller** I have to initialize **pageNumber** parameter with **"1"** (Default page number). The problem is the blue activated button on page 1 that remains there no matter which page **button link** you click. Moreover this **button** is also missing the actionLink.

One last thing I am integrating my **search** with **pagination** as you can see in the controller code.

[image: Paged List]

```
public PartialViewResult List_Items(string keyword, int? page)
{
    var newlists = from s in db.TrMs
                   orderby s.S1
                   select s;

    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    int pageSize = 10;
    var data = newlists.Where(f => f.S1.ToString().Contains(keyword) && f.S100 == vt).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return PartialView(data);
}
```

Here is the generated **Html** for PagedList in my **view**

```
<div class="pagination-container">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="active">
            <a>1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#searchResult" href="/TrM/Search_Items?keyword=&amp;page=2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#searchResult" href="/TrM/Search_Items?keyword=&amp;page=3">3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#searchResult" href="/TrM/Search_Items?keyword=&amp;page=4">4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="PagedList-skipToNext">
            <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#searchResult" href="/TrM/Search_Items?keyword=&amp;page=2" rel="next">»</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is how I am using the pagination helper.

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("List_Items", "TrM", new {keyword="", page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "searchResult" }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paging controls are most likely outside of the **searchResult** container. When you click on a page you're replacing the table but not the paging controls. Move your paging controls inside of your **searchResult** container!

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right! Thankyou! The "searchResult" tag was actually placed inside a table. That's why it was not rendering and updating this DIV properly. Thanks again!